# Error: car.reviews.find() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a problem with the method `find()`. In my MERN stack app, I want to add a `reviews` route where every user can add comments about any car in the app.

In the front end, I added fields and buttons; In the back end, I added a post request, but when I run it in the browser and try to add a review, the console logs a status code of `500` and says that `car.reviews.find()` is not a function. I haven't found the problem. Can you help me?

I add the code below :

**carRoutes.js**

```
carRouter.post(
        '/:id/reviews',
        isAuth,
        expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
          const carId = req.params.id;
          const car = await Car.findById(carId);
          if (car) {
           
            if (car.reviews.find((x) => x.name === req.user.name)) {
              return res
                .status(400)
                .send({ message: 'You already submitted a review' });
            }
      
            const review = {
              name: req.user.name,
              rating: Number(req.body.rating),
              comment: req.body.comment,
            };
          
            car.reviews.push(review);
            car.numReviews = car.reviews.length;
            car.rating =
              car.reviews.reduce((a, c) => c.rating + a, 0) /
              car.reviews.length;
            const updatedCar = await car.save();
            res.status(201).send({
              message: 'Review Created',
              review: updatedCar.reviews[updatedCar.reviews.length - 1],
              numReviews: car.numReviews,
              rating: car.rating,
            });
          } else {
            res.status(404).send({ message: 'Product Not Found' });
          }
        })
      );
```

**CarScreen.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { DatePicker} from 'antd'
import { useContext, useEffect, useReducer, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import Badge from 'react-bootstrap/Badge';
import Rating from '../components/Rating';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet-async";
import LoadingBox from "../components/LoadingBox";
import MessageBox from "../components/MessageBox";
import { getError } from "../utils";
import { Store } from "../Store";
import moment from 'moment';
import FloatingLabel from 'react-bootstrap/FloatingLabel';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

const {RangePicker} = DatePicker;


const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
    
      case 'REFRESH_CAR':
            return {...state, car:action.payload};
      case 'CREATE_REQUEST': 
         return {...state, loadingCreateReview: true};
      case 'CREATE_SUCCESS':
         return {...state, loadingCreateReview: false};
      case 'CREATE_FAIL': 
        return {...state, loadingCreateReview: false};

      case 'FETCH_REQUEST': 
         return {...state, loading: true};
      case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
         return {...state, car: action.payload, loading: false};
      case 'FETCH_FAIL': 
        return {...state, loading: false, error: action.payload};
      default: 
        return state;
    }
  };

function CarScreen() {
    let reviewsRef = useRef();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const params = useParams();
    const {model} = params;
    
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
    const [comment, setComment] = useState('');
    const [fromDate, setFromDate] = useState();
    const [toDate, setToDate] = useState();
    const [totalHours, setTotalHours] = useState(0);
    const [totalAmount, setTotalAmount] = useState(0);
    
    const [{ loading,error,car, loadingCreateReview}, dispatch]=useReducer(reducer, {
        car: [],
        loading: true,
        error: '',
      });
      //  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);
        useEffect(()=>{
          const fetchData = async () =>{
            dispatch({type: 'FETCH_REQUEST'});
            try{
               const result = await axios.get(`/api/cars/model/${model}`);
               dispatch({type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result.data});

            }catch(err){
              dispatch({type: 'FETCH_FAIL', payload: getError(err)});
            }
           
          };
          fetchData();
        }, [model]);
       
    const {state, dispatch: ctxDispatch} = useContext(Store);
    const {userInfo} = state;
    

    const addToCartHandler = async () => {
      
        ctxDispatch({
            type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM',payload: {...car, quantity: 1, totalAmount, fromDate, toDate},
        })
        navigate('/cart');
    }
    function selectTimeSlots(values){

        setFromDate(moment(values[0]).format('MMM DD yyyy HH:mm'));
        setToDate(moment(values[1]).format('MMM DD yyyy HH:mm'));
        setTotalHours(values[1].diff(values[0], 'hours'));
    }

    const submitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!comment || !rating) {
          toast.error('Please enter comment and rating');
          return;
        }
        try {
          const { data } = await axios.post(
            `/api/cars/${car._id}/reviews`,
            { rating, comment, name: userInfo.name },
            {
              headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
            }
          );
    
          dispatch({
            type: 'CREATE_SUCCESS',
          });
          toast.success('Review submitted successfully');
          car.reviews.unshift(data.review);
          car.numReviews = data.numReviews;
          car.rating = data.rating;
          dispatch({ type: 'REFRESH_PRODUCT', payload: car });
          window.scrollTo({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            top: reviewsRef.current.offsetTop,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          toast.error(getError(error));
          dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_FAIL' });
        }
      };

      const obj = (car.pricePerHour);

      useEffect(()=> {
        setTotalAmount((totalHours * obj))
      }, [totalHours, obj]);
     

    return loading? (
        <LoadingBox />
        ) : error? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
        ) : (
        <div>
            <Row>
                <Col md={6}>
                    <img
                     className="img-large"
                     src={car.image}
                     alt={car.mark}
                     ></img>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <ListGroup variant="flush">
                        <ListGroup.Item> 
                            <Helmet>
                                <title>{car.mark}</title>
                            </Helmet>
                            <h1>{car.mark}</h1>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <Rating rating={car.rating}
                            numReviews={car.numReviews}
                            ></Rating>

                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <p>Status:</p>
                            {car.available === true ? (
                                <Badge bg="success">Available</Badge>
                            ) : (
                                <Badge bg="danger">Unavailable</Badge>
                            )
                            }
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        
                        <ListGroup.Item>Price per hour : ${car.pricePerHour}</ListGroup.Item>
                        
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            Description:
                            <p>{car.description}</p>
                        </ListGroup.Item>

                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <RangePicker showTime={{format: 'HH:mm'}} format="MMM DD yyyy HH:mm" 
                            onChange={selectTimeSlots}/>

                            <div>
                                <p>Total Hours : <b>{totalHours}</b></p>
                                <p>Rent per Hour: <b>{car.pricePerHour}</b></p>

                                <h3>Total Amount : ${totalAmount}</h3>

                            </div>

                        </ListGroup.Item>

                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            {car.available === true && (
                               // <Link to='/personaldata'>
                                    <Button onClick={addToCartHandler} variant="primary">
                                        Rent a car    
                                    </Button>
                               // </Link>
                            )}
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                    
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <div className="my-3">
                <h2 ref={reviewsRef}>Reviews</h2>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  {car.reviews}{
                    <MessageBox>There is no review</MessageBox>
                  }
                </div>
            <ListGroup>
            {car.reviews?.map(review => (
                    <ListGroup.Item key={review._id}>
                    <strong>{review.name}</strong>
                    <Rating rating={review.rating} caption=" "></Rating>
                    <p>{review.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</p>
                    <p>{review.comment}</p>
            </ListGroup.Item>
          ))}
        </ListGroup>
        <div className="my-3">
          {userInfo ? (
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
              <h2>Write a customer review</h2>
              <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="rating">
                <Form.Label>Rating</Form.Label>
                <Form.Select
                  aria-label="Rating"
                  value={rating}
                  onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <option value="">Select...</option>
                  <option value="1">1- Poor</option>
                  <option value="2">2- Fair</option>
                  <option value="3">3- Good</option>
                  <option value="4">4- Very good</option>
                  <option value="5">5- Excelent</option>
                </Form.Select>
              </Form.Group>
              <FloatingLabel
                controlId="floatingTextarea"
                label="Comments"
                className="mb-3"
              >
                <Form.Control
                  as="textarea"
                  placeholder="Leave a comment here"
                  value={comment}
                  onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                />
              </FloatingLabel>

              <div className="mb-3">
                <Button disabled={loadingCreateReview} type="submit">
                  Submit
                </Button>
                {loadingCreateReview && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
              </div>
            </form>
          ) : (
            <MessageBox>
              Please{' '}
              <Link to={`/signin?redirect=/car/${car.model}`}>
                Sign In
              </Link>{' '}
              to write a review
            </MessageBox>
          )}
        </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
        );
}

export default CarScreen;
```

**Car schema in MongoDB:**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        comment: {type: String, required:true},
        rating: {type: Number, required: true},
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

const carSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        mark: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        model: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        year: {type: Number, required: true},
        category: {type: String, required: true},
        capacity: {type: Number, required:true},
        fuelType: {type: String, required: true},
        transmission: {type: String, required: true},
        image: {type: String, required: true},
        pricePerHour: {type: Number, required: true},
        pricePerDay: {type: Number, required: true},
        available: {type: Boolean},
        rating: {type: Number},
        numReviews: {type: Number},
        description: {type: String, required: true},
        reviews: {reviewSchema}
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

const Car = mongoose.model('Car',carSchema);
export default Car;
```

**Update:**

The error was in Car Schema structure. I corrected "reviews : [reviewsSchema]".

But after I added new review in front end , the browser wrote :

```
ERROR
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, comment, rating, _id, createdAt, updatedAt}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:77740:13)
    at createChild (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:77952:11)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78169:29)
    at reconcileChildFibers (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78511:20)
    at reconcileChildren (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81443:32)
    at updateFragment (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81747:7)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:83547:18)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68518:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68562:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68619:35)
```

Comment: you have not shared the structure of your `Car` object, ensure `car.reviews` is an array then only you can perform array `find` function.

Comment: I added Car model here and saw the error. It was not an array. After correct , I added successfully a review in front end , but after that the browser says me 
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, comment, rating, _id, createdAt, updatedAt}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the `reviews` property to an array in `Car`, you should write:

```
<div className="my-3">
    <h2 ref="{reviewsRef}">Reviews</h2>
    <div className="mb-3">
        {car.reviews && car.reviews.length > 0 ?
        <ListGroup
            >{car.reviews.map(review => (
            <ListGroup.Item key="{review._id}">
                <strong>{review.name}</strong>
                <Rating rating="{review.rating}" caption=" "></Rating>
                <p>{review.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</p>
                <p>{review.comment}</p>
            </ListGroup.Item>
            ))}</ListGroup
        >
        : <MessageBox>There is no review</MessageBox>}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! The users can add reviews successfully